# Nagios plugin check_hwinfo not working

Tags: nagios, nsclient++

I am using Nagios to monitor Windows hosts. I am using Nagios 3.5 running on a Centos 7 server. The following packages have been installed from the official repositories and from the EPEL repository:

```
nagios
nagios-plugins-all
nagios-plugins-nrpe
```

So far I am using the 'check_nt' method to run some basic checks on the windows hosts. This is working fine.

Now I want to use the [check_hwinfo](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/check_hwinfo/details) plugin to gather information about the hosts in a single place. This plugin requires NRPE in order to run.

In the 'commands.cfg' file I have added:

```
define command{
    command_name    check_hwinfo
    command_line    $USER1$/check_nrpe_hwinfo $HOSTNAME$ $HOSTADDRESS$
}
```

In  the 'nrpe.cfg' I have added:

```
command[check_hwinfo]=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_hwinfo.pl
command[check_hwinfo_csv]=/usr/bin/sudo /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_hwinfo.pl -t csv

command[check_hwinfo]=c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe //NoLogo //T:10 "C:check_hwinfo\check_hwinfo.wsf"
command[check_hwinfo_csv]=c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe //NoLogo //T:10 "C:\check_hwinfo\check_hwinfo.wsf" /sep:csv
```

I have copied the 'check_hwinfo.pl' script in the '/usr/lib64/nagios/plugins' folder and made it executable, with identical permissions with the other scripts in the folder.

I have added these lines to '/etc/sudoers' in order to execute without password:

```
Defaults:nagios      !requiretty
nagios ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_hwinfo.pl "", /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_hwinfo.pl -t csv
```

On the client side, I am running NSClient++ on the Windows hosts I am monitoring. For check_hwinfo I made the folder 'C:\check_hwinfo' and put inside the 'check_hwinfo.wsf' file needed for running the test on Windows.

This is my [nsclient.ini](http://pastebin.com/2htUsJvU) and this is my [nsclient-full.ini](http://pastebin.com/c4U5kacQ) files.

While all the other checks (via check_nt) are working fine, check_hwinfo refuses to work no matter what I try. The service status in the Nagios page is 'WARNING' and the error message is 'No handler for command: check_hwinfo_csv'.

Does anybody have experience with check_hwinfo? Can you please point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE 1:**

When trying to run check_nrpe manualy I get this:

```
./check_nrpe -H 192.168.10.13 -c CheckDisk
No handler for command: checkdisk
```

It is the same as the error message I get at the GUI from the check_hwinfo plugin

```
No handler for command: check_hwinfo_csv
```

**UPDATE 2:**

In the Windows client, in the nsclient-full.ini file I have the following definitions:

```
check_hwinfo=C:\check_hwinfo\check_hwinfo.wsf
check_hwinfo_csv=C:\check_hwinfo\check_hwinfo.wsf -t csv
```

Comment: Can NRPE sudo without password?

Comment: @ChristopherPerrin I have actually taken care of that in the /etc/sudoers file. See the update.

Comment: Show us the output of a manual test, running check_nrpe manually.

Comment: Wait... you know you have to define the check_hwinfo commands on the Windows side, right? If you're asking about a Windows box, nothing starting with "/usr/lib64" is relevant at all. Also, there is no Nagios 6.5

Comment: @Keith Fixed the typo. It is now 'Nagios 3.5'. Also, there is no mention of '/usr/lib64...' on my windows hosts. Tomorrow I will run the manual check and report back here.

Comment: @Keith Check update

Comment: What version of NSClient++ are you using? Or are you using Winrpe?

Comment: @Keith It is 0.4.1 x64, the latest stable version.

Comment: Can we see your command definition for check_hwinfo_csv from the NSclient++ configuration?

Comment: @Keith Check update for definitions in nsclient-full.ini

Answer (score 0):

That error indicates that you don't have the external script handler enabled. Fortunately, [nsclient++ has excellent documentation](http://docs.nsclient.org/howto/external_scripts.html) on this subject.

(Looks like they're currently in the process of re-doing the wiki/docs, so you might want to check the [old one](http://nsclient.org/nscp/wiki/guides/nagios/external_scripts) too if something's missing.)

Comment: I have enabled external scripts the way it is described in the article.